# CSS Scrollbar appearance for overflow auto with max-height

Tags: css

```
     {
        overflow: auto;
         max-height: 100px;
     }
```

With the above, the scroll bar appears for an empty list of items. It works fine without max-height but occupies space and the element after the scroll is pushed by the height.

Any possible solution, so that the scroll bar appears only after the max-height is reached.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YrE3M/ seems to work for me

Comment: Which browser it is happening?

Comment: Thanks Dharman, tried at jsfiddle.net that works. Some other thing is corrupting perhaps.